# 'NoneType' object is not callable, how to avoid errors?

Tags: python, nonetype, callable-object

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f42eb9e8dd56> in <module>
      5 model_name = 'tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase'
      6 torch_device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
----> 7 tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
      8 model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name).to(torch_device)
      9 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

```
import torch
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer
model_name = 'tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase'
torch_device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name).to(torch_device)

def get_response(input_text,num_return_sequences,num_beams):
  batch = tokenizer([input_text],truncation=True,padding='longest',max_length=60, return_tensors="pt").to(torch_device)
  translated = model.generate(**batch,max_length=60,num_beams=num_beams, num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences, temperature=1.5)
  tgt_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)
  return tgt_text
```

I was take this code from https://huggingface.co/tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase and I was install library !pip install SentencePiece !pip install sentence-splitter and !pip install transformers